# How to locate which css include is used for an element

Tags: css, styles

I'd like to use the same color as the H2 element for some text in a JSP page. But there are 7 style sheets included in the page, as can be seen from view source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lib/jqModal.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/en-US/localized.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lib/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lib/jquery-ui-theme.css" />
```

How do I determine which style sheet is used for the H2 element?

Comment: Fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name says, CSS - Cascades. So wherever the `h2` is defined, the browser fetches the rule and applies it to the page. So, let's say we have included a few style-sheets, like how I have done in my application [Soceall](http://pkp4d.com/), which has a lot of plugins CSS than my own.

If you see in the Chrome's Dev Tools Inspector, you could find all the cascading rules for, say, I picked a `<h4>` here:

[image]

It gets from three style-sheets and the line numbers are also displayed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/formvalidation/formvalidation/master/dist/css/formValidation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.8.0/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" />
```

So, here:

[image]

Clicking on the link, which says, `style.css:277` will take you to the declaration on style-sheet as well. You can also edit the file and see the changes lively.

[image]

Comment: Just did it - SE makes you wait a few minutes. Thanks again, the page is already updated :)

Comment: @JackBeNimble Yes... I know... 15 mins. But glad that you got to know where you wanna search for. :) Hope I helped you a bit. Let me know if you need more clarifications.